# Instal Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I tired to install Ubuntu on Windows 10:
1. Prepared the USB drive using Universal USB Installer
2. pressed F12 to go to boot menure
3. selected the USB boot option
4. Selected Install rather than Try
5. then instead of proceeding to install Ubuntu, the Screen blinked and booted in Windows instead.

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable hibernation and Fast Boot in Windows.

Open command prompt as administrator.

Execute this command :  `powercfg /h off`

Open the old version of the Windows Control Panel.
Open Power Settings, enable show hidden settings.
Uncheck Fast startup in case that it still is enabled.

Shutdown the machine completely, do NOT reboot.
Start the computer - select the USB (UEFI) option ...

Maybe the install media is not configured properly.
Now create the Ubuntu installation media this way :

Open command prompt as administrator.

Execute these commands :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file - copy the whole content to the USB drive.

Comment: Hello, I did all the above and still has the same. and I tired this time with Ubuntu 15

Comment: @azyaser : Please boot into BIOS and check whether Secure Boot is enabled ... in case it is : disable it ! :)

Comment: well, i tried again and the boot menu says legacy is On, secure is OFF. and the UEFI options has only boot manager and my SSD. the USB appears under the Legacy

Comment: @azyaser : Did you install Windows in legacy BIOS mode or in UEFI mode ?

Comment: The machine came with Win 10 installed. it is a Dell XPS 15 9550

Comment: Thanks for this, all went fine except the Format. it gives me invalid argument

Comment: Sorry, but tried three times all sequence and nothing happened, could the USB be defected?

Comment: It worked finally. I am copying the data and will try to boot UEFI and install again. Appreciate your patience and help

Comment: Man! You are a genius! It sees the flash and I am setting things up. Much appreciated

Comment: Hello, it is me again :-). The installation freezes at the logo purple screen. For an hour now. Is that normal?

Comment: I did post a question